# Why can we still read Byte values in Python

Tags: python, file, byte

So I tried converting my data into Bytes so that it won't be easily readable by Humans...
But somehow, in Python Bytes apparently mean having b' and ' at either side of my string. I don't see any string to byte conversion going on.

```
>>> bytes('hello', 'utf-8')
b'hello'
>>> 'hello'.encode('utf-8')
b'hello'
```

Comment: What you see is a human readable representation of the bytes object produced by its `__repr__` method. In general what a user sees is always a representation of some kind.

Comment: I tried writing it into a file, and I can read it as well, but that's not supposed to happen ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say byte, I suppose you want to convert into bits.

```
>>> a = 'stackoverflow'
>>> b = bytes(a, 'utf-8')
>>> c =  ' '.join(["{0:b}".format(x) for x in b])
>>> c
'1110011 1110100 1100001 1100011 1101011 1101111 1110110 1100101 1110010 1100110 1101100 1101111 1110111'


>>> ' '.join(map(bin,bytearray(b)))
'0b1110011 0b1110100 0b1100001 0b1100011 0b1101011 0b1101111 0b1110110 0b1100101 0b1110010 0b1100110 0b1101100 0b1101111 0b1110111'
```

Another 3rd part library [Bitarray](https://pypi.org/project/bitarray/) is also handy in these situations.

```
>>> import bitarray
>>> a = bitarray.bitarray()
>>> a
bitarray()
>>> a.frombytes('stackoverflow'.encode('utf-8'))
>>> a
bitarray('01110011011101000110000101100011011010110110111101110110011001010111001001100110011011000110111101110111')
>>> a.tobytes()
b'stackoverflow'
```

Comment: But why is it that I could read it even after writing it into a file AS binary ?

Comment: write the byte array, you might have converted the values while writing. Or the editor that you're using might convert the byte array, decoding it...